# How to write unit test for Material UI slider? "Error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" thrown when attempting to render component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

Trying to test the Material-UI Slider with Reat-Test-Renderer gets an error: `Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null]`

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dan-r0lb8?file=/src/App.test.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { Slider } from "@material-ui/core";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

it("should render", () => {
  renderer.create(<Slider />);
});
```

This is not the case with any other Material UI components that I know of.

It seems to be related to forwardRef as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#ideas), but I could not figure out a way to get it to work.

**EDIT** Unfortunately switching over to `@testing-library/react` is not an option this project I'm working on.

**EDIT 2** The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to render and test a more complex component of my own which contains the Slider. It took me a while to figure out that this is what's causing the issue, and the code above is the minimal amount of code to replicate the issue.

**EDIT 3** Error message screenshot
[image]

Comment: I am not getting the error when I run the test ?

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine I have updated my question with an image from code sandbox

Comment: on it I will debug it and hope get back with an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Test Renderer only renders the components as a JS object rather than to a browser environment. Hence, anything that uses dom based refs will have this issue. Related jest issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5462.

There is a section in the React Docs for a way to workaround it:  https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#ideas

EDIT:

Here's a working test. It likely makes a lot of the functionality of the slider not work, since we are setting the internal refs to null. But it does run. The "Next" branch on MUI doesn't have the `findDOMNode` function there, so that might be easier to work with.

I wasn't able to get these to work on CodeSandbox because `jest` was undefined, and I couldn't find how to fix that.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Slider } from '@material-ui/core';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
  // the useIsFocusVisible function in Slider.js (MUI component) uses findDOMNOde
  // Luckily it checks if there's nulls, so we can return a null
  // https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/utils/useIsFocusVisible.js#L136
  findDOMNode: () => null,
}));
it('should render', () => {
  renderer.create(<Slider />);
});
```

If you want to try and mock the full functionality (sort of), you can use this implementation of the findDOMNode mock, which will return the values that are needed for the `useIsFocusVisible` to run successfully including adding the event listener:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Slider } from '@material-ui/core';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.mock('react-dom', () => ({
  // the useIsFocusVisible function in Slider.js (MUI component) uses findDOMNOde
  // https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/utils/useIsFocusVisible.js#L136
  findDOMNode: (instance) => {
    return { ownerDocument: instance };
  },
}));
it('should render', () => {
  let eventListenerFn = jest.fn();
  renderer.create(<Slider />, {
    createNodeMock: (element) => {
      if (element.type === 'span') {
        return {
          addEventListener: eventListenerFn,
        };
      }
    },
  });
});
```

In order to figure out how to get these tests to succesfully run, I had to step through the error stacks/MUI source code to find out what's going wrong and what values were needed to be mocked in order to not throw errors.

---

Original, showing how much better @testing-library is for this:

However, may I suggest using [@testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro)? It's nice to work with and uses jsdom to render the components so it'll work with this component.

I went ahead and made a couple of random tests for the `Slider` using the testing library to show that it works with `Slider` and throws no errors:

```
import React from "react";
import { Slider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

it("should render", () => {
  render(<Slider />);
});

it("should render an input", () => {
  const component = render(<Slider />);
  const input = component.baseElement.querySelector("input");
  expect(input).toBeDefined();
});

it("Should have the correct value", () => {
  const component = render(<Slider value={50} />);
  const input = component.baseElement.querySelector("input");
  expect(input.value).toBe("50");
});
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rhodes-lvucl?file=/src/App.test.js)

Comment: I personally love `testing-library/react` too. Unfortunately the project I'm working in uses `react-test-renderer` and it's not possible to switch over now. I am aware of the section you linked from the React docs, I just don't know how to applyit to the Slider component properly :/

Comment: I'm not really sure you can... I was trying to make it work, but it also looks like they are using findDOMNode, which makes it even more complicated. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-leakey-ebk1j?file=/src/App.test.js Is my best guess so far, but I can't seem to get jest.mock to exist. This is based on this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7371#issuecomment-323516392. Other parts comments in the thread say mocking findDOMNode properly in this is impossible, so take from it what you will.

Comment: @davidx1, I figured it out! Take a look and see if that gets you further. As I mentioned I couldn't get things to run through CodeSandbox, not sure why.